# Suppose a coin, which lands heads with probability 1/3 (and tails with probability 2/3) each time it is flipped, is flipped 5 consecutive times.

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

What is the conditional probability that the number of times the coin lands
heads is at least 3, conditioned on the event that the coin lands tails at least
once?

---

---

Firstly, I think they meant I need to find $P(H \geq 3 \mid T \geq 1)$ where H and T are just random variables that denote the number of times a head or a tail comes up, respectively.

I first calculated $P(T \geq 1)$ which would be $$\sum_{i=1}^5 (2/3)^i(1/3)^{5-i}$$ since it's a binomial distribution.

Then I found $P(H \geq 3 \text{ and } T \geq 1)$ by finding the probabilities that $P(H = 3 \text{ and } T = 2)$ or $P(H = 4 \text{ and } T = 1)$.

Lastly, I just divided $P(H \geq 3 \text{ and } T \geq 1)$ by $P(T \geq 1)$.

Is this a good way of solving the above question?

Comment: Yes, that is the correct intended approach.

Comment: I would have not calculated $Pr(T\geq 1)$ as you did, but instead have calculated it as $Pr(T\geq 1) = 1 - Pr(T=0) = 1-\frac{1}{3^5}$ which would be much easier to find.  Further, your attempt at calculating $Pr(T\geq 1)$ directly, you forgot your binomial coefficients.  It should have been $\sum\limits_{i=1}^5\color{red}{\binom{5}{i}}(2/3)^i(1/3)^{5-i}$

Comment: @JMoravitz  Yes, I forgot to put the binomial coefficient in for that expression. That does seem like a much easier way to calculate the Pr(T≥1). Thanks!!!